# add two letters from a variable in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

im working to make my code take an input (word) and output the sum of all the letters in the input, the letters would be equal to there numeric value- a=1 b=2 c=3 etc,here is my unfinished code so far:-

```
echo enter word
read word
for let in $word
do
echo $let

*here is where it should take the input and calculate the output (w+o+r+d = ??)
```

Comment: What are you stuck with, specifically?

Comment: I'm stuck with making the script add the letters of the variable together, for instance I enter the word "hello" into the script, I want it to add the letters of the word "hello" together using 1-24 as the letters a-z, does that make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses an **associative array** to map (English) letters to their ordinal values. Note that associative arrays require **bash 4.0 or higher**.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Declare variables.
declare -i i sum  # -i declares integer variables
declare -A letterValues # -A declares associative arrays, which requires bash 4+
declare letter # a regular (string) variable

# Create a mapping between letters and their values
# using an associative array.
# The sequence brace expression {a..z} expands to 'a b c ... z'
# $((++i)) increments variable $i and returns the new value.
i=0
for letter in {a..z}; do
    letterValues[$letter]=$((++i))
done

# Prompt for a word.
read -p 'Enter word: ' word

# Loop over all chars. in the word
# and sum up the individual letter values.
sum=0
for (( i = 0; i < ${#word}; i++ )); do
  # Extract the substring of length 1 (the letter) at position $i.
  # Substring indices are 0-based.
  letter=${word:i:1}
  # Note that due to having declared $sum with -i,
  # surrounding the following statement with (( ... ))
  # is optional.
  sum+=letterValues[$letter]
done

# Output the result.
echo "Sum of letter values: $sum"
```

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over the characters of a string, do this:

```
string="hello world"
for ((i=0; i < ${#string}; i++)); do
    char=${string:i:1}       # substring starting at $i, of length 1
    echo "$i -> '$char'"
done
```

```
0 -> 'h'
1 -> 'e'
2 -> 'l'
3 -> 'l'
4 -> 'o'
5 -> ' '
6 -> 'w'
7 -> 'o'
8 -> 'r'
9 -> 'l'
10 -> 'd'
```

Comment: I think that the OP is looking to use the "alphabetical value" e.g. `a => 1`, `b => 2`

Comment: Ok thanks alot, could you explain a little? I'm teaching myself to code so any explanation would be great